# User Profile Sync - User Names displayed as MVID=

Tags: user-profile-service, fim

Noticed that during the final couple stages of an incremental active directory sync for my user profile service, the FIM Synchronization Service Manager lists the users distinguished names as MVID=(Random series of numbers and letters, looks like an ID)

When i double click on the item and look at the details for the user i can see their information properly but the distinguished name is not in a name format but in some sort of ID format.

Anyone ever seen this an know what causes this to happen?

Running a 2013 farm on March 2013 PU.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any ideas???

Comment: I've not been able to get anywhere on this...still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you should see is the CN= in the properties pane. If you don't something is missing. Dou your synchronization account (SP_ProfileSync) have "replicate directory changes" permission in your AD?

This is what I see in the distinguished name field:

[image]